# What to do when I need to call owner owner's owner method?

Tags: delphi, collections, delphi-xe2

I've got TbsManager class which expose Load method like:

```
 TbsManager = class(TComponent)
 private
   FItems: TbsItems;  
 public
   procedure Load(Item: TbsItem);
```

The TbsItem is a TCollectionItem and it's owned by TbsItems:

```
TbsItem = class(TCollectionItem)
TbsItems = class(TCollection)
```

I want my TbsItems to have the Load method (which is in the onwer's owner class) and this is how I achieved it:

```
procedure TbsItem.Load;
begin
  TbsManager(TbsItems(GetOwner).Owner).Load(Self);
end;
```

I'm not sure if I've done it right. Is it a safe code?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your wording. Your bsitems won't HAVE the load method they just call owners owner owner method.

Comment: @PieterB I don't want to rewrite the Load() code in TbsItem, so I'm calling TbsManager Load method (which Loads the current TbsItem). Hope I've made it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your design mandates that hierarchy then your code is reasonable. I'd modify it to use checked casts, with the `as` operator. These will raise runtime errors if the classes are not of the required type:

```
((GetOwner as TbsItems).Owner as TbsManager).Load(Self);
```

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez I don't see where constructors come into this. Can you explain.